# How to turn on start date and end date same time when i click in start date react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

How can i turn on start date and end date same time when i click on start date. I use react-datepicker. Thank you guys

[image]
code:

```
<div>
        <span className={classes.date}>Start Date</span>
        <DatePicker
          className={classes.datePicker}
          selectsStart
          selected={rangeStart}
          startDate={rangeStart}
          endDate={rangeEnd}
          onChange={selectStartDate}
          dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy"
        />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.ml10}>
        <span className={classes.date}>End Date</span>
        <DatePicker
          className={classes.datePicker}
          selectsEnd
          selected={rangeEnd}
          startDate={rangeStart}
          endDate={rangeEnd}
          onChange={selectEndDate}
          minDate={rangeStart}
          dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy"
        />
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the list of [props](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md), it has a prop: `startOpen: <bool>`.

```
<DatePicker startOpen={true} ... />
```